# Filter Log from console in Android

Tags: android

I'm new in android and I'm using android studio to build app. Sometimes I need to check variable values I set log for them but It's very difficult to find a single log line out of too many lines So, I need to filter the logs.

```
  Log.i("Some info", "Show some thing here");
```

I'm using `Android 2.2.3`. In this studio I'm not able to find any filter Here is image of console.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get filter options in the Android Monitor panel, but not in the Debug panel. If you don't have Android Monitor on your toolbar, you can open it from `View -> Tool Windows -> Android Monitor`, or `Alt + 6` on Windows by default.

You get a couple of filter options in the upper right of the panel:

- Log levels (verbose, debug, info, etc.)
- A simple text filter field where you can filter either for plaintext or regex
- A filter for where to show log messages from, you'll probably use the default `Show only selected application` option here.

[image: Filters in Android Monitor]